# Cant Connect to HBase in a Docker instance

Tags: scala, docker, hbase, playframework-2.2

I have created an HBase instance running on a Docker container. I have been able to create a table in it from HBase Shell using the docker container's bash shell and am also able to access it from the HBase Rest API.

However I am not able to access it from the the Play Framework using Scala, I constantly get the following exception.

```
MasterNotRunningException |com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: 238b057263fb
```

Here is the Scala code that throws the exception.

```
val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
var hbaseRunning = false;

config.clear
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.18.0.2");  // This ip Address was retrieved by doing a docker inspect on the docker container
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181")
config.set("hbase.master", "172.18.0.2:60000");
config.setInt("timeout", 25000);

try{
  println(" Check if HBase is Running")
  HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);   // This line throws the exception
  println(" HBase is Running")              // Because this line doesnt print.
  hbaseRunning = true
}catch{
  case ex: MasterNotRunningException => {
    println(" MasterNotRunningException |" + ex.getMessage)  // This is the exception I get
  }
}
finally println(" HBase is NOT Running")
```

Here is Hbase-Site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>file:///opt/hbasedata</value>
</property>
```

**Edit: My Docker file is part of a larger docker compose and I am publishing the docker ports. My ports section in the docker-compose is as follows**

```
    ports:
  - 2181:12181
  - 60000:60000
  - 60010:60010
  - 60020:60020
  - 60030:60030
  - 2471:2471   // this is for the rest API
```

I am able to access HBase and manipulate data from the Shell and from the Rest API, only the access from Play Framework using the Java API fails. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Why does it say `unknown host: 238b057263fb` if you have configured an ip rather than a hostname?

Comment: @kliew, Beats me! I have not configured the hostname anywhere. That number is the container ID of the docker image, and changes every time I run  `docker-compose up`. Yet in the error the correct hostname corresponding to the IP address pops up in the error message.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your Dockerized cluster is tracking the master by its hostname inside the Docker network.

You either need to:

1. run your Play app in a container within that network (so that it can resolve the master hostname)

or

2. start your containers with the `-h <hostname>` (or equivalent compose markup) and make sure that your Play server maps that hostname to the right ip (by `/etc/hosts` or DNS). The `-h` option will cause your cluster to report an internal (to the Docker network) fqdn for the master and the mapping on the Play side will point your Play application from the internal fqdn to the real address.

Comment: This was exactly my issue - I added my docker-container-id to map to 127.0.0.1 locally and it was fixed. However, I don’t understand why this is needed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: By default, docker uses the container id as the hostname for each container. You can override with a hostname using `-h`. These hostnames are still only visible within the virtual network interface where all containers reside. Your physical machine does not use these hostnames because it uses a different network interface with a different host resolver.

Comment: I see. But strangely I was able to connect to the zookeeper inside the container via `127.0.0.1`. I just couldn't connect to hbase via `127.0.0.1`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Glide : Can you share your /etc/hosts. I am having the same problem.

Comment: @supermonk Sorry, I don't have it anymore as this was awhile ago.

Comment: @Glide just add something like `127.0.0.1 7a7b0e35abf1` to the hosts file (replacing 7a7b0e35abf1 with *your* container hostname)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access container ports from outside of the container, you need to publish those ports using `-p <host port>:<guest port>` when running `docker run ~`

Comment: Thanks, But I have published the ports. That is why I am able to access HBase using the Rest API. Let me edit the question with that info.